# Inserting text string with hex into PostgreSQL as a bytea

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a text file with several strings of hex in it:

```
013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb
007687fc64b746569616414b78c81ef1
```

I would like to store these in the database as a *bytea*, instead of a *varchar*. That is, I would like the database to store 01 as the single byte 00000001, not characters '0' & '1'.

I can easily run this file through sed to format/escape it any way I need to.

This is what I have tried:

```
create table mytable (testcol BYTEA);
```

This works:

```
insert into mytable (testcol) values (E'\x7f\x7f');
```

However, as soon as I have a byte that goes above \x7f, I get this error:

```
insert into mytable (testcol) values (E'\x7f\x80');
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80
```

Any ideas, or am I approaching things wrong?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can convert a hex string to bytea using the `decode` function (where "encoding" means encoding a binary value to some textual value). For example:

```
select decode('DEADBEEF', 'hex');
      decode      
------------------
 \336\255\276\357
```

which is more understandable with 9.0's default output:

```
   decode   
------------
 \xdeadbeef
```

The reason you can't just say `E'\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF'` is that this is intended to make a text value, not a bytea, so Postgresql will try to convert it from the client encoding to the database encoding. You could write the bytea escape format like that, but you need to double the backslashes: `E'\\336\\255\\276\\357'::bytea`. I think you can see why the bytea format is being changed.... IMHO the `decode()` function is a reasonable way of writing inputs, even though there is some overhead involved.

Answer (score 42):

```
INSERT INTO
  mytable (testcol)
VALUES
  (decode('013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb', 'hex'))
```

Comment: This saved my day. SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE testcol= (decode('013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb', 'hex')); will then match that `bytea` column.

Answer (score 7):

## The Ruby Way

I recently needed to read/write binary data from/to Postgres, but via Ruby. Here's how I did it using the [Pg library](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/).

*Although not strictly Postgres-specific, I thought I'd include this Ruby-centric answer for reference.*

### Postgres DB Setup

```
require 'pg'
DB = PG::Connection.new(host: 'localhost', dbname:'test')
DB.exec "CREATE TABLE mytable (testcol BYTEA)"
BINARY = 1
```

### Insert Binary Data

```
sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (testcol) VALUES ($1)"
param = {value: binary_data, format: BINARY}
DB.exec_params(sql, [param]) {|res| res.cmd_tuples == 1 }
```

### Select Binary Data

```
sql = "SELECT testcol FROM mytable LIMIT 1"
DB.exec_params(sql, [], BINARY) {|res| res.getvalue(0,0) }
```

Comment: this answer is hiding too much abstraction for the OP

Answer (score 6):

### Introduction

This is an updated answer that includes both how to insert but also how to  query.

It is possible to convert the hex into a bytea value using the [`decode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-binarystring.html) function. This should be used for both querying and also inserting.

This can be used for both inserting but also querying.

[Example SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=83c5b3fe9bcb111bd5f96c75f93ceadf)

### Querying Existing Data

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE testcol = (decode('013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb', 'hex'));
```

### Encode vs Decode for Querying

A user had asked the following:

> How does searching the bytea field by hex value after inserting it?
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE myHexField =
> (encode('013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb', 'hex'));
> ```
>
> does not work.

In the documentation [Binary String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-binarystring.html), they have the description of both `encode` and `decode`.

```
   +==================================+=============+=======================================================================================================+=======================================+============+
    |             Function             | Return Type |                                              Description                                              |                Example                |   Result   |
    +==================================+=============+=======================================================================================================+=======================================+============+
    | decode(string text, format text) | bytea       | Decode binary data from textual representation in string. Options for format are same as in encode.   | decode('123\000456', 'escape')        | 123\000456 |
    +----------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
    | encode(data bytea, format text)  | text        | Encode binary data into a textual representation. Supported formats are: base64, hex, escape. escape  | encode('123\000456'::bytea, 'escape') | 123\000456 |
    |                                  |             | converts zero bytes and high-bit-set bytes to octal sequences (\nnn) and doubles backslashes.         |                                       |            |
    +----------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
```

So you will notice that `Encode` is for `encoding binary data into a textual string` and returns text. However, since we are storing `bytea` we have to use `decode` for both inserting and querying.

### Inserting

```
create table mytable (testcol BYTEA);

INSERT INTO
  mytable (testcol)
VALUES
  (decode('013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb', 'hex'));
```

From: see [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3103461/1688441)

Answer (score 4):

From: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html

```sql
INSERT INTO
  mytable (testcol)
VALUES
  ('\x013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb'::bytea);
```

Comment: This is the only answer useful for me here.

Answer (score 0):

[More](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-binarystring.html) and sundry [options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) where `testcol` is of type `bytea`:

```
-- how to insert the string "123[a char of value zero]abc456"
insert into mytable (testcol) values decode(E'123\\000abc456', 'escape');

-- how to insert the string "123abc456"
insert into mytable (testcol) values decode(E'123abc456', 'escape');

-- how to insert in base64: insert string "abc456"
insert into mytable (testcol) values decode('YWJjNDU2', 'base64');
```