# How to convert SQLite SQL dump file to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, migration

For development I'm using SQLite database with production in PostgreSQL. I updated my local database with data and need to transfer a specific table to the production database.

Running `sqlite database .dump > /the/path/to/sqlite-dumpfile.sql`, SQLite outputs a table dump in the following format:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "courses_school" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY, "department_count" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "the_id" integer UNIQUE, "school_name" varchar(150), "slug" varchar(50));
INSERT INTO "courses_school" VALUES(1,168,213,'TEST Name A',NULL);
INSERT INTO "courses_school" VALUES(2,0,656,'TEST Name B',NULL);
....
COMMIT;
```

How do I convert this into a PostgreSQL compatible dump file I can import into my production server?

Comment: Well, that command did not work for me until I changed **sqlite** to **sqlite3**

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You should be able to feed that dump file straight into `psql`:

```
/path/to/psql -d database -U username -W < /the/path/to/sqlite-dumpfile.sql
```

If you want the `id` column to "auto increment" then change its type from "int" to "serial" in the table creation line. PostgreSQL will then attach a sequence to that column so that INSERTs with NULL ids will be automatically assigned the next available value. PostgreSQL will also not recognize `AUTOINCREMENT` commands, so these need to be removed.

You'll also want to check for `datetime` columns in the SQLite schema and change them to `timestamp` for PostgreSQL. (Thanks to [Clay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373402/clay) for pointing this out.)

If you have booleans in your SQLite then you could convert `1` and `0` to `1::boolean` and `0::boolean` (respectively) or you could change the boolean column to an integer in the schema section of the dump and then fix them up by hand inside PostgreSQL after the import.

If you have BLOBs in your SQLite then you'll want to adjust the schema to use `bytea`. You'll probably need to mix in some [`decode` calls as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3103416/479863). Writing a quick'n'dirty copier in your favorite language might be easier than mangling the SQL if you a lot of BLOBs to deal with though.

As usual, if you have foreign keys then you'll probably want to look into [`set constraints all deferred`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) to avoid insert ordering problems, placing the command inside the BEGIN/COMMIT pair.

Thanks to [Nicolas Riley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6372/nicholas-riley) for the boolean, blob, and constraints notes.

If you have `` ` `` on your code, as generated by some SQLite3 clients, you need to remove them.

PostGRESQL also doesn't recognize `unsigned` columns, so you might want to drop that or add a custom-made constraint such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    ...
    unsigned_column_name integer CHECK (unsigned_column_name > 0)
);
```

While SQLite defaults null values to `''`, PostgreSQL requires them to be set as `NULL`.

The syntax in the SQLite dump file appears to be mostly compatible with PostgreSQL so you can patch a few things and feed it to `psql`. Importing a big pile of data through SQL INSERTs might take a while but it'll work.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!  This worked great for me.  I had a program doing this migration at first but it was way too slow and causing other problems.  Correction to your command.  It should be -d, not -D.

Comment: One note if anyone else has this problem, SQLITE had my null values as ''.  POSTGRESQL requires NULL.  So fire up vim and do the command: %s/''/NULL/g to fix the dump file.

Comment: No, you want to keep the transaction to avoid some overhead.

Comment: I think Peter may be right.  Although mu's answer is working right now (and is how I got the migration working), according to this FAQ it is even better to keep the BEGIN/COMMIT:

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

Comment: Transactions: Presumably PostgreSQL will have to commit each INSERT to disk without the big transaction wrapping the whole thing but, with the transaction wrapper, it'll just queue up a big blob of stuff and do one big write at the end. Right? And thanks for the correction on the `psql` switches.

Comment: This works great. I would also note that if you need to migrate sqlite `datetime` columns, that you have to change them to `timestamp` for postgres.

Comment: @Clay: Thanks for that, I included that in the answer for posterity.

Comment: A few more issues I ran into: changing `BLOB` into `BYTEA` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103242/), changing 0/1 for `BOOLEAN` columns to '0'/'1', and deferring constraints (`DEFERRABLE` / `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED`).

Comment: @NicholasRiley: Thanks for that. I gave this up to a community wiki since it has turned into a group effort, fair is fair.

Comment: Also ``unsigned`` should be dropped.

Comment: You can use to_timestamp() in the postgreSQL to convert a timestamp to a progreSQL timestamp

Comment: I'd note that the `integer` type in Sqlite defaults to 8 bytes, while the `integer` type in PostgreSQL is 4 bytes. To be safe, you may want to convert your `integer`-typed columns in Sqlite to the `bigint` type in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Also be aware that SQLite stores timestamps with zone by default, PostgreSQL does not. If you need to preserve time zone information, you can use `timestamptz` as column type. For more details see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: `ERROR:  relation "sqlite_sequence" does not exist` at `DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;` how to solve that?

Comment: @ZekeDran Remove it from the SQL dump or use one of the solutions? I'm not even sure where that's coming from.

Comment: Should remove `DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;` and replace `INSERT INTO "sqlite_sequence" VALUES('locations',7);` with `ALTER SEQUENCE locations_id_seq RESTART WITH 8;` and it works...!

Comment: "You should be able to feed that dump file straight into psql" This doesn't work at all. The dumped sqlite sql file needs significant conversion, which your comments allude to but don't completely explain. Were you expecting OP to manually edit an gigabyte sized sql file?

Comment: @Cerin The file as posted eight years ago (!) was pretty much a simple "clean up and dump into `psql`" job. In the general case that's not true so I gave up the answer as a community wiki (i.e. I get nothing for this and it is easy for the community as a whole to update and maintain and complain about and whatever).

Comment: As @SaravanabalagiRamachandran mentioned, Postgres sequences must be restarted, which can be quite tedious (I just did it :-) ). Plus a very interesting thing: I had a REAL column in my Sqlite DB containing percentages with 1 digit after the decimal point, e.g. `34.5`. Interestingly after migrating to Postgres these values became like `34.499999` or similar such things. Had to run the `ROUND(value, prec)` function on them to clean them up.

Comment: the sqlite3 output has table names with capitals which are quoted in the create table statement, but not in the insert into statements, so inserts fail. Another little gotcha

Answer (score 90):

## [`pgloader`](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader)

I came across this post when searching for a way to convert an SQLite dump to PostgreSQL. Even though this post has an accepted answer (and a good one at that +1), I think adding this is important.

I started looking into the solutions here and realized that I was looking for a more automated method. I looked up the wiki docs:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL

and discovered `pgloader`. Pretty cool application and it's relatively easy to use. You can convert the flat SQLite file into a usable PostgreSQL database. I installed from the `*.deb` and created a `command` file like this in a test directory:

```
load database  
    from 'db.sqlite3'  
    into postgresql:///testdb 
       
with include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences  
         
set work_mem to '16MB', maintenance_work_mem to '512 MB';
```

like the [docs](http://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#loading-sqlite-files-with-pgloader) state. I then created a `testdb` with `createdb`:

`createdb testdb`

I ran the `pgloader` command like this:

`pgloader command`

and then connected to the new database:

`psql testdb`

After some queries to check the data, it appears it worked quite well. I know if I had tried to run one of these scripts or do the stepwise conversion mentioned herein, I would have spent much more time.

To prove the concept I dumped this `testdb` and imported into a development environment on a production server and the data transferred over nicely.

Comment: Beware that (still supported) Ubuntu distributions might have outdated version - v2.x.y are already deprecated and don't actually work. v3.2.x might work but v3.2.3 is recommended. I have fetched v3.2.3 from bleeding edge and installed with _sudo dpkg -i <.deb file name>_, it had no problem with dependencies.

Comment: I concur with @silpol - be sure to download the latest stable release and install using your fav package manager; for the "command" file this is just a text file called 'command' with no extension name (i.e. no need for .txt at the end of the file name) you don't need to put the file name in angular brackets; i had to change the search_parth of the psql database in order to see my data; pgloader works well and saved me a great deal of hassle

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling when I encountered this issue, and that tool made it so easy... Sometimes things just work out nicely, don't they?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on windows.

Answer (score 32):

The [sequel gem](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) (a Ruby library) offers data copying across different databases:
http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/bin_sequel_rdoc.html#label-Copy+Databases

First install Ruby, then install the gem by running `gem install sequel`.

In case of sqlite, it would be like this:
`sequel -C sqlite://db/production.sqlite3 postgres://user@localhost/db`

Comment: Awesome solution. Much easier than fiddling around with `pgloader`.

Comment: Absolutely, pgloader is messy, the GC seems to crash on huge databases: https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/962

Comment: Feel free to post your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148421/how-to-convert-a-postgres-database-to-sqlite/64222183#64222183 where I copied your answer. Then ping me and I will revoke my answer if you want the reps for it.

Comment: @Felix thanks! You can take the credit. Could you swap the order of DB references around (since it wants PG to SQLite), oh and add one more "la" to my id. The answer may also be less helpful though since it requires them installing PG on dev machine, and at that point they'd just use PG for development.

Comment: @lulalala Thanks. Did that. But about the reasoning I disagree. They could e.g. convert the db on the linux machine and then copy it over to the dev machine (as sqlite db file). But anyway all in all its a bad idea :) But sequel saved my ass here in a nasty situation.

Comment: sequel gem worked like a charm.

Answer (score 18):

You can use a one liner, here is an example with the help of sed command:

```
sqlite3 mjsqlite.db .dump | sed -e 's/INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT/SERIAL PRIMARY KEY/g;s/PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;//;s/unsigned big int/BIGINT/g;s/UNSIGNED BIG INT/BIGINT/g;s/BIG INT/BIGINT/g;s/UNSIGNED INT(10)/BIGINT/g;s/BOOLEAN/SMALLINT/g;s/boolean/SMALLINT/g;s/UNSIGNED BIG INT/INTEGER/g;s/INT(3)/INT2/g;s/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP/g' | psql mypqdb mypguser
```

Comment: there is no replace for LONG type, e.g.

Comment: one more item could be added
`sed -e 's/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP/g'`

Comment: `sed -e 's/TINYINT(1)/SMALLINT/g'`  -- and for a comparison of all the data types see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942586/comparison-of-database-column-types-in-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite-cross-map

Comment: I also had a problem with a SMALLINT that defaulted to 't' or 'f' in the sqlite. Obviously a boolean, but not familiar enough with either db system to recommend a safe fix.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTOINCREMENT"`

Comment: Replace `' | sed -e '` with `; `  :)

Comment: get this error
ERROR:  column "time" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bigint
LINE 1: ...o":null,"notNullable":false,"unsigned":true}]}]}',1673471190..

Comment: My dump had a `"id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,` at some point, so the casing was different to your `sed`s. Maybe all of them should be case insensitive by changing `/g` to `/gi`? Not sure about the implications

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a script to do the `sqlite3` to `postgres` migration.  It doesn't handle all the schema/data translations mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581921/1303625, but it does what I needed it to do.  Hopefully it will be a good starting point for others.

https://gist.github.com/2253099

Comment: This works well! I've forked the Gist and added some insights as a comment: https://gist.github.com/bittner/7368128

Answer (score 5):

Try these steps...

Step 01: Dump sqlite db to json

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```

Step 02: Create tables without migration

```
python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Step 03: Open django shell. Then exclude contentype data

```
python3 manage.py shell
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
quit()
```

Step 04: Load Data

```
python3 manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Comment: for large GB JSON files huge ram required

Comment: Thanks a million for this. Why should content types be excluded?

Answer (score 2):

pgloader work wonders on converting database in sqlite to postgresql.

Here's an example on converting a local sqlitedb to a remote PostgreSQL db:

pgloader **sqlite.db** postgresql://**username**:**password**@**hostname**/**dbname**

Comment: Pgloader is terribly buggy and unreliable. It immediately crashes with the error `KABOOM! Control stack exhausted (no more space for function call frames).`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried editing/regexping the sqlite dump so PostgreSQL accepts it, it is tedious and prone to error.

What I got to work really fast:

First recreate the schema on PostgreSQL without any data, either editing the dump or if you were using an ORM you may be lucky and it talks to both back-ends (sqlalchemy, peewee, ...).

Then migrate the data using pandas. Suppose you have a table with a bool field (which is 0/1 in sqlite, but must be t/f in PostgreSQL)

```
def int_to_strbool(df, column):
    df = df.replace({column: 0}, 'f')
    df = df.replace({column: 1}, 't')
    return df

#def other_transform(df, column):
#...

conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
df = pd.read_sql(f'select * from {table_name}', conn)

df = int_to_strbool(df, bool_column_name)
#df = other_transform(df, other_column_name)

df.to_csv(table_name + '.csv'), sep=',', header=False, index=False)
```

This works like a charm, is easy to write, read and debug each function, unlike (for me) the regular expressions.

Now you can try to load the resulting csv with PostgreSQL (even graphically with the admin tool), with the only caveat that you must load the tables with foreign keys after you have loaded the tables with the corresponding source keys. I did not have the case of a circular dependency, I guess you can suspend temporarily the key checking if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

SyncLite (https://www.synclite.io) provides SQLite connector for numerous instances of applications each creating several SQLite databases, to perform a real-time database replication/consolidation into one or more databases/data warehouses/data lakes of your choice, while maintaining live replicas of source SQLite dbs. This gives rise to many interesting architectural possibilities for building all kinds of data intensive applications around SQLite.

Additionally,the SyncLite database replication/migration tool provides an ability to replicate/migrate data from pre-existing SQLite database files into a wide range of DBs/DWs/DataLakes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35414916)