# Ruby & SQLite & Heroku & PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, sqlite, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

I've a simple Sinatra application which I've developed using SQLite. The database is a simple two-column table: an ID and a string entry.

I would like to deploy this app to Heroku. What's the least painful way to convert an SQLite database to PostgreSQL, understanding that PostgreSQL is required to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: this seems to be almost duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581727/convert-sqlite-sql-dump-file-to-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

For simple use cases `heroku db:push` will push your local sqlite database into your Heroku Postgres database.

It's worth considering then switching to using Postgres locally and then use `heroku db:pull` to bring the database back from Heroku to your new local postgres instance.

I'll caveat to say that whilst `heroku db:pull` works for SIMPLE databases once you start using more complex Postgres datatypes then you need to use something like `heroku pg:transger` which is Postgres > Postgres only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `taps` gem, as shown in [this Railscast](https://github.com/radar/forem/issues/421).

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to install Postgres on your local machine so you can make changes and easily deploy to heroku. Second you'll want to migrate from SQLite to Postgres. I just did the migration for my own Rails app following Heroku's instructions and it took less 5 minutes. Seems simple enough.

The instructions to migrate are [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) (even has instructions on installing Postgres locally). Then you can follow the Heroku [getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction) for the rest.