# How do I use the command "heroku pg:transfer"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I am very new to heroku/ruby on rails and git.  I just went through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and want to push my local database to heroku but am having trouble.

After doing some research I found this article:

[pg transfer is the new taps](http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/pgtransfer-is-the-new-taps/)

It seems like it should work, but I do not understand how to set my env var `DATABASE_URL`:

```
$ env DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/someapp-dev heroku pg:transfer
```

Specifically I have no idea what I am supposed to directly copy and what to change.  I believe I need to enter my own local host and my own database name.

Is this correct?  If so how do I find my localhost and how do I find my database name?

My database.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to copy production db to your app running locally?

Comment: I'm trying to copy my local database (wherever that is, I'm not sure where it is) to heroku.  I basically saved some user names/passwords locally that I want to work on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding - you must use a Postgresql database on Heroku.  When I pushed an application to Heroku I changed the databases to Postgresq al part of the push - including in Dev.  Looking at the link you provided I get the impression it means the database you are copying from is also Postgresql (as opposed to SQLite).

Comment: This link is to a stackoverflow question whichshould help-converting SQLite to Postgresql - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581727/convert-sqlite-sql-dump-file-to-postgresql - Pierre