# how to open SQLite DB in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want SQLite database file open in PostgreSQL. Please give to me Answer,Before
We are Useing Sqlite Database Now We are Moveing into PostgreSql Database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SQLITE SQL dump file to POSTGRESQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581727/convert-sqlite-sql-dump-file-to-postgresql)

Comment: PostgreSQL has [Foreign Data Wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) which can directly connect to a SQLite database

Comment: If you are moving to a PostgreSQL then better to do it through db dump as duplicate instructs. If there is too much manual job altering the dump maybe creating the dump with help of foreign data adapter for SQLite is a better solution.