# Import .db file to postgresql using terminal

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, postgresql-13

I am on ubuntu, i have Postgresql 13 installed on it. I have a file named (order.db) which is actually a database with a few tables in it. I want to import whole of (order.db) into postgres with same database name and of course the data. Is there any way to do it using terminal? any command?

The order.db file was created with the help of sqlite3 collaborating with c++. Order.db had nothing to do with postgresql at earlier phases of my project. I just want this (order.db) file to be imported as a database to my postgres.

Comment: How was that file created? Please **[edit]** your question and show us the exact `pg_dump` command you used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert SQLITE SQL dump file to POSTGRESQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581727/convert-sqlite-sql-dump-file-to-postgresql)

Comment: I have edited the question with more details. can you have a look?