# Is there an alternative way to import data into Postgres than using psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, import, dbeaver

I am under strict corporate environment and don't have access to Postgres' `psql`. Therefore I can't do what's shown e.g. in the SO [Convert SQLITE SQL dump file to POSTGRESQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581727/convert-sqlite-sql-dump-file-to-postgresql). However, I can generate the sqlite dump file `.sql`. The resulting `dump.sql` file is 1.3gb big.

What would be the best way to import this data into Postgres? I also have `DBeaver` and can connect to both databases simultaneously but unfortunately can't do INSERT from SELECT.

Comment: You can use `psql` on a remote machine to connect.

Comment: What can you access other than a crippled DBeaver? Perl?  Python?  R?

Comment: @jjanes I have Python available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term for that is 'absurd', not 'strict'.

DBeaver has an 'execute script' feature.  But who knows, maybe it will be blocked.

Comment: Thanks but DBeaver 'execute script' is based on `psql` :((( so it complains that `psql` isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

EnterpriseDB offers [binary downloads](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries). If you unzip those to a local drive you might be able to execute psql from the `bin` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install psycopg2 or pg8000 for python, you should be able to connect to the database and then loop over the dump file sending each line to the database with `cur.execute(line)` .  It might take some fiddling if the dump file has any multi-line commands, but the example you linked to doesn't show any of those.