# How to copy data from SQLite to postgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite

I have a task and I need to copy data from one SQLite table to almost identical postgreSQL table. I wrote a code that doesn't work and I can't figure out what's the problem. It prints that connection was established successfull, shows no errors, but when I go to the terminal to check `content.film_work` table with command `SELECT * FROM content.film_work;` I don't see the data. It shows:

```
movies_database=# SELECT * FROM content.film_work;



created | modified | id | title | description | creation_date | rating | type | file_path 
---------+----------+----+-------+-------------+---------------+--------+------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

Here are some steps:

1. Connect to the SQLite database and copy data from film_work table to dataclass.
2. Pass list of dataclasses instances with table rows to another function whee I connect to the postgreSQL.
3. Connect to the postgreSQL and get postgreSQL table (content.film_work) column names to pass it to the INSERT SQL query.
4. Before all this I change the order of columns to correctly pass data from SQLite to postgreSQL.

**SQLite table (film_work):**

```
0|id|TEXT|0||1
1|title|TEXT|1||0
2|description|TEXT|0||0
3|creation_date|DATE|0||0
4|file_path|TEXT|0||0
5|rating|FLOAT|0||0
6|type|TEXT|1||0
7|created_at|timestamp with time zone|0||0
8|updated_at|timestamp with time zone|0||0
```

**postgreSQL table (content.film_work):**

```
 created | modified | id | title | description | creation_date | rating | type | file_path
```

**Code snippet:**

```
psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()
db_path = 'db.sqlite'

@contextmanager
def conn_context(db_path: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        conn.close() 

@dataclass
class FilmWork:
    created_at: date = None
    updated_at: date = None
    id: uuid.UUID = field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4)
    title: str = ''
    description: str = ''
    creation_date: date = None
    rating: float = 0.0
    type: str = ''
    file_path: str = ''


def __post_init__(self):
    if self.creation_date is None:
        self.creation_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    if self.created_at is None:
        self.created_at = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    if self.updated_at is None:
        self.updated_at = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    if self.description is None:
        self.description = 'Нет описания'
    if self.rating is None:
        self.rating = 0.0


def copy_from_sqlite():
    with conn_context(db_path) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM film_work;")

        result = cursor.fetchall()

        films = [FilmWork(**dict(film)) for film in result]

        save_film_work_to_postgres(films)

def save_film_work_to_postgres(films: list):
    psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()
    dsn = {
        'dbname': 'movies_database',
        'user': 'app',
        'password': '123qwe',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 5432,
        'options': '-c search_path=content',
    }

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**dsn)
        print("Successfull connection!")

        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'film_work' ORDER BY ordinal_position;")
            column_names_list = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]            
            column_names_str = ','.join(column_names_list)

            col_count = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(column_names_list)) 
            bind_values = ','.join(cursor.mogrify(f"({col_count})", astuple(film)).decode('utf-8') for film in films)

            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO content.film_work ({column_names_str}) VALUES {bind_values} """)
    except psycopg2.Error as _e:
        print("Ошибка:", _e)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
    

copy_from_sqlite()
```

Comment: Read [psycopg2 Transaction](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control). Hint, commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert SQLite SQL dump file to PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581727/how-to-convert-sqlite-sql-dump-file-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

check if this code execute correctly made some changes: data formatting, field      initialization and fixed the column name mismatch

```
import sqlite3
import psycopg2
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime
from psycopg2 import extras
from uuid import UUID

psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()
db_path = 'db.sqlite'

@contextmanager
def conn_context(db_path: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        conn.close() 

@dataclass
class FilmWork:
    created_at: datetime = None
    updated_at: datetime = None
    id: UUID = field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4)
    title: str = ''
    description: str = ''
    creation_date: datetime = None
    rating: float = 0.0
    type: str = ''
    file_path: str = ''

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.creation_date is None:
            self.creation_date = datetime.now()
        if self.created_at is None:
            self.created_at = datetime.now()
        if self.updated_at is None:
            self.updated_at = datetime.now()
        if self.description is None:
            self.description = 'Нет описания'
        if self.rating is None:
            self.rating = 0.0

def copy_from_sqlite():
    with conn_context(db_path) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM film_work;")

        result = cursor.fetchall()

        films = [FilmWork(**dict(film)) for film in result]

        save_film_work_to_postgres(films)

def save_film_work_to_postgres(films: list):
    dsn = {
        'dbname': 'movies_database',
        'user': 'app',
        'password': '123qwe',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 5432,
        'options': '-c search_path=content',
    }

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**dsn)
        print("Successful connection!")

        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'film_work' ORDER BY ordinal_position;")
            column_names_list = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]            
            column_names_str = ','.join(column_names_list)

            col_count = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(column_names_list)) 
            bind_values = ','.join(cursor.mogrify(f"({col_count})", film).decode('utf-8') for film in films)

            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO content.film_work ({column_names_str}) VALUES {bind_values} """)
            conn.commit()  # Don't forget to commit changes
    except psycopg2.Error as _e:
        print("Ошибка:", _e)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

copy_from_sqlite()
```

Comment: ``` with conn.cursor() ``` automatically commit changes and closes transactions, isn’t it?

Comment: it does not but it ensures that the cursor is closed when you exit the block defined by the with statement