Attempting to convert SQLite .db to PostgreSQL throws encoding error
I'm trying to convert my SQLite database (.db file which has been used with python's aiosqlite library) to a PostgreSQL database i have set up, however im encountering this error when attempting to do so.

What could be causing this error? Is there a better way to go about this?

First off, don't share commands as screenshots only, include them as text. Nothing seems to make sense about the command in your screenshot. -p 3 suggests PostgeSQL would be running on port 3, which has to be a mistake. -d is typically followed by a name and -U by a username, but there're none there (unless you blacked the names and the rest of the port number out, which makes the screenshot even more useless). Finally < file.ext would pipe any SQL from the file into the session, which would make sense if this was some createdb.sql file, but you're just redirecting a binary in.

You'd want to have SQLite export the SQL statements required to recreate the database, and they would have to be fully compatible with PostgreSQL's SQL, which may require either performing a limited export, or using a tool that specifically exports the SQL for PostgreSQL's consumption.

Sorry, here is the command: sudo psql -p 7368 -d newdb -U postgresuser -W < /root/EconomyX/economyx.db
I do realize now that there is a difference between .db. and .sql, but im not sure how to convert. .db is all i have as its all the library creates/utilizes

Ok, i did convert the database and its data to .sql via SQLite db browser, and am trying the conversion that way. Works better, but i get this spammed instead: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block ROLLBACK

Read back to my previous comment - SQL for SQLite is not exactly the same as SQL for PostgreSQL and you'll need to find a way to get around the incompatibilities. There's probably tools out there that can help with that.

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4581727/12621346 ?
Personally I would export csv from sqlite and insert this file to the PostgreSQL database.

The real answer to this question is: Export your .db via a browser of sorts (for example, in my case, SQLite browser) to .sql and the command will run correctly (of course after making your exported sql statements compatible with postgresql)
