# How can I print bytea data as a hexadecimal string in PostgreSQL / pgAdmin III?

Tags: postgresql, hex, pgadmin

I have a fairly short (14-byte) `bytea` data column in my database. I would like to print it as a hexadecimal string.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Based on [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3103416/900130), I found my solution to be

```
SELECT encode(my_column::bytea, 'hex') FROM my_table;
```

Comment: @Zero are you using it on PostgreSQL or another database? Could you post the command you're using and the exact and complete error message?

Comment: `select ... encode(k1.keyword, 'hex')`: `ERROR:  function encode(character varying, unknown) does not exist`

Comment: In pg 9.6.1, I had to coerce the column to the bytea type to get this to work: `SELECT encode(my_column::bytea, 'hex') FROM my_table;`