# Is there a good reason to insert HEX as BYTEA in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-binary.html) from the documentation:

> ... binary strings specifically allow storing octets of value zero and
>   ... octets outside the range 32 to 126 ...

To me that sounds like there is no reason to use BYTEA to store a HEX value? Still a lot of people seem to use BYTEA for sth. [like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3103242/1602492) this:

```
013d7d16d7ad4fefb61bd95b765c8ceb
007687fc64b746569616414b78c81ef1
```

Is there a good reason to do so?

Comment: I think the other question is quite clear in why that may be the right thing to do: when stored as BYTEA `013d` is stored as two bytes, when stored as a string, the same value will be stored as four characters `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`. Ie, more compact and also, if these are actually raw bytes, no useless conversions will need to be applied so it's probably more efficient in the end. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: No, no, thank you. It just took a little longer for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three good reasons:

1. It will require less storage space, since two hexadecimal digits are stored as one byte.
2. It will automatically check the value for correctness:

   ```
   SELECT decode('0102ABCDNONSENSE', 'hex');
   ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal digit: "N"
   ```
3. you can store and retrieve binary data without converting them from and to text if your API supports it.